# What do the "\" do in PHP / MySQL scripts

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a PHP script that performs simple actions to a data base.  In order to obtain the MySQL queries I use `phpmyadmin` to generates the PHP.  When I generates using `phpmyadmin` the commands for example creates a table, this is the result:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `pyr`.`table1` (`id` INT NOT NULL) ENGINE = MyISAM COMMENT = \'Some comments...\';";
```

If I insert this on my PHP script, it doesn't work.  However, if i remove the `\`, it works.  What does the `\` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *escapes* the character `'` so it can be written in your string. But you only have to escape the simple quote if your string is enclosed within single quotes. In your example, it's enclosed within **double** quotes, so you don't have to escape simple quotes! For example :

```
$a = "I'm a cat"; // no need to escape
$b = 'I\'m a cat'; // you have to escape, otherwise
                   // the second ' would be interpreted as the end of your string!
$c = "He says : \"I'm a cat\""; // You have to escape the double quotes
                                // in this case, because your string is enclosed
                                // within double quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

Phpmyadmin designed this query to be used with single quotes:

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE `pyr`.`table1` (`id` INT NOT NULL)
ENGINE = MyISAM COMMENT = \'Some comments...\';';
```

In this case, the backslashes correctly escape the single quotation marks to tell PHP that they aren't the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

It escapes the quotes in your queries

Answer (score 0):

That is a way to 'escape' quotation marks so you can use the same quotes within a quoted string.

A correct example would be

```
$somestring="This string has \"quotes\" in it";
```

But this example is incorrect. There is no need to escape single quotes within that string, because it is double quoted.

See the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), specifically this part

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash ()